# flutter sql : got error on return text[list[i], ['item_name']

Tags: sql, json, flutter, crud

i got error on return text(list[i],['item_name']) //at bottom of coding .
this is my coding in main.dart

please help me, it doesn't show what error to fix

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        return Text(list[i], ['item_name']);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: `['item_name']` you need to provide variable name

Comment: how to provide?

Comment: You have written only index name. This index name must belong to some map. That map's name is required.